# MongoDB array turned into string on database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have problem with Mongo/express array parsing. A array from body seems to be correct when I console.log response in node console. But the problem is when I try to save the body to mongo.db using insert.one method, the post is saved but the array turns into string, which is bad for me.

This is what I'm sending to mongo (the data is ok, i console.log it, array is not string here)

```
{
  createdBy: this.userName,
  postContent: this.post,
  tags: this.tags,
  addedAt: new Date()
};
```

And this is what is stored in database

[image]

Update:
When I hardcode array into payload it's showed correctly as an array in mongo.
But of course problem still exist for dynamic data

Comment: How is your schema defined for this collection?

Comment: I don't have schema, I'm not using mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use JSON parse along with a replace to force it to accept the string as an array, like this:

```
const array = JSON.parse(this.tags.replace(/'/g, '"'));
```

Then set tags to the value of `array`:

```
tags: array
```

Comment: It throws an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Comment: @KacperŁukasik I just realized that you're missing a single quote on the last item in the array. Is this a typo or is that how your actual value is reflected? I believe that the missing single quote is the problem. Fix that and it will parse correctly.

Comment: Oh, sorry it works now. But there is no "cleaner" way to do that?

Comment: Well, defining a schema in a library such as mongoose helps mitigate these types of situations... Other than that, I'd have to see how you're sending the array from the client; perhaps there's an issue there. Either way, it's not like this solution creates some crazy amount of overhead that you need be concerned about. Should be fine.

Comment: The body is sending via postman like that {
 "post": "fmxcsjdfmxcsjd",
 "tags": "['asd', 'asd', 'asd']"
}

Comment: In that case, you should be able to pass it as a JSON array and select the raw option.

Comment: Oh it works, I doesn't know that I should send array not as a string. Thank's for help!

Answer (score 0):

Use data type as array -- 4 and use .pretty().

Generally if you use find() method returns data in a dense format.
By using cursor.pretty() you can set the cursor to return data in a format that is easier for humans to parse

Comment: But I need this to be stored in mongo.db as an array, because of future features.

Comment: what is the data type you used it for storing in Mondo DB.  Below link is usefull for Mongodb data type references https://dzone.com/articles/data-types-in-mongodb